# How to improve ArUco marker tracking on mp4 video footage

Tags: opencv, python

I am using ArUco markers to track two points in my research project experimental setup. One marker is on the base of a robot, and the other is on the robot tip. The footage is recorded using OpenCV at 40 FPS, and the entire experiment lasts for 72 seconds. This would mean I expect to see around 2880 datapoints for each coordinate value (x, y, z; I do not need rotation), however when the tip marker is in motion is when I lose points. Is there a way to slow down the playback on the video or slow down OpenCV's processing of the video so that I could get these missing points? I've included a gif of the robot, it is a generally arc-shape trajectory. Thank you.
[image: robot bending with two aruco markers attached]

EDIT: Below I have added my function where I get the poses of my two ArUco markers.

```
kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8)

def get_aruco_pose(im):
    global rvec, tvec
    im = cv.dilate(im, kernel, iterations=1)

    corners, ids, rejectedCandidates = cv.aruco.detectMarkers(im, 
                                                              DICT, 
                                                              parameters=PARAM)
    transf = None
    if len(corners) > 0:
        # flatten the ArUco IDs list
        ids = ids.flatten()
        # loop over the detected ArUCo corners
        for (markerCorner, markerID) in zip(corners, ids):
            rvec, tvec, _ = cv.aruco.estimatePoseSingleMarkers(markerCorner, ARUCO_LENGTH_MM, CAMERA_MATRIX, DIST_COEFF)
            # Draw aruco
            show_aruco(im, markerCorner, markerID) # uncomment to show markers in video
            rmat, _ = cv.Rodrigues(rvec)
            tvec    = tvec.reshape(3, 1)
            transf  = np.concatenate((rmat, tvec), axis = 1)

            if markerID == 3:
                tvec_bs.append(tvec)
            if markerID == 4:
                tvec_fs.append(tvec)
    return tvec
```

Comment: if there is the information in the frame ,  in each frame , you do not need to slow down the video frame rate.  But you can try  'cv2.waitKey(1000)'   to wait 1 second between each frame.  So you can Check every frame . I think the frames with no information are blurry so it is the real problem.  In this case you can try  functions like  cv2.erode  or cv2.dilate , to better view the marker .

Comment: Thank you. I have tried adding a line with cv2.dilate, however when I use it to return a new frame, my function then complains that my transformation vector is undefined. Would cv.dilate do this? I've edited my original post to include my function, with the addition of cv.dilate.

Comment: Out-of-focus Deblur Filter  , google it .   The easiest way to fix this would be to buy an expensive webcam. But most of all the quality of the frame information depends on the light. So first of all I would try to use the right lighting and slow down the movements of your creature. When the software does what you need in the most hostile conditions, using excellent hardware will give you much more possibilities.

Comment: **shine more light** on the scene.

Answer (score 3):

Actually this problem is not related with the software but the hardware. Since your system has a speed, it causes motion blur in your images. In your code loop, it already checks each frame to detect aruco but it seems not successfull because of the motion blur.

Your camera has a parameter which we call it **exposure time**. This is the time limit you are capturing each image you get. Exposure time is related with the target objects speed. There is not a constant ration not to get blurry images but you can only choose available camera by your experiences.

So what you can do to figure out the problem:

- You can change the camera with a higher fps
- You can decrease the speed of the platform to decrease motion blur

Answer (score 0):

[image]

the problem is evident in the attached image. Another approach to solving the problem would be to recognize the problem. You now have different markers visually, but you know they represent the same marker in motion and rotation. So you can recognize them.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think in the interest of time I must simply interpolate points between recognised coordinates, but I appreciate your help in parsing out this problem.